# PhpStorm MySQL Connector/J stopped working after update to 5.1.40

Tags: php, mysql, intellij-idea, phpstorm

After PhpStorm suggested to update MySQL driver, my existing and working connections to MySQL databases had stopped working. I saw this problem reproduced on my Ubuntu and on another Mac. The error I received was:

> [08S01] Communications link failure.

I use SSH tunneling to access the databases. Also, I use the latest stable version of PhpStorm (2017.1.2). The driver versions that caused troubles were 5.1.40 and 5.1.41 which I installed manually while trying to fix the problem.

Is there a quick way to fix that? I really need to continue working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the latest versions of MySQL Connector/J have some issues. The solution is to rollback to use the previous version of MySQL Connector/J driver in PhpStorm. In my case, the previous version was 5.1.35, which is working fine.

The problem is that the rollback is not that obvious. I didn't have the previous version in a driver selection popup:

[image: missing versions in driver selection]

The solution was to add an additional driver file that already existed on my PC:

[image: add additional driver button]

Once I added the driver, the last step was to disable the "Use provided driver" checkbox:

[image: disable the checkbox "Use provided driver"]

Then I applied the changes, and the connections worked again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

There is also an ability to add a driver to the list of MySQL Connector.

[image]

In order to do that, follow the steps below:

1. Navigate to IDE's settings/configurations folder ([instructions here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs)).
2. Enter the `./jdbc-drivers/` folder. You should see in its content something like this:
   [image]
3. In `./MySQL Connector/J/` create a new folder with the version number, in my case is `5.1.35` (as my previous driver file is `./mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar`)
   [image]
4. Copy the file `./mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar` into the just created version folder (`5.1.35`). So it'll look like this:
   [image]
5. Now, edit the file `./jdbc-drivers.xml`.
   [image]
6. Copy the whole `<artifact>` block with the name `MySQL Connector/J` with the newer version (in my case `5.1.40`), paste it below and change the version for this block to your new version (in my case `5.1.35`). It should look something like this:
   [image]
7. Save the file and restart the IDE.
8. Got to MySQL driver editor (as @yury-fedorov stated), and now you should see the older version.

You can repeat these steps for [any other version](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-j/) you like.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to type your db (3306) and SSH ports (in my case it was 22)