# How to connect Google Cloud SQL to PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect my Google Cloud SQL instance to [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) however in attempting to do so, I am running into an issue where I cannot connect due to the Driver (or perhaps the url, I am not sure). I have followed a seemingly outdated [tutorial](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/08/connecting-to-google-cloud-sql-from-phpstorm/) but it has not worked. I have download google_sql_tools from online like the tutorial suggests. While I can follow some of the tutorial to set it up, when I specify the driver as Google JDBC driver and fill in my credentials, it still fails with 1 of 2 errors:

- Google Driver class cannot be instantiated from the jar file.
- Wrong Driver/Connection failed

[image][image]

There isn't much documentation online about issues that may arise while trying to do this. I have included images of the error message and the settings. Would appreciate it if someone can guide me to the right way to do this.

Comment: No personal experience with Google Cloud ... so I may be very wrong here.... but I have noticed that you are trying to connect using MySQL driver (you have added Google driver files to that entry). I say -- 1) create custom driver entry (using that green `+` button -- use last option in the list) where only Google Cloud JDBC file would be present and try that way. 2) What other driver classes are available?

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for the response, I tried your suggestion, created a custom driver with the jar file present and selected all drivers available for that jar file:

- com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Driver
- com.google.cloud.sql.Driver
- com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.googleapi.GoogleApiDriver

And none has had a successful connection.

Comment: OK then. 1) Please read these pages first (just in case) and apply their logic (from what I see no separate driver is needed and native MySQL connection should work...). But you most likely will need to whitelist your IP to be able to connect 2) You may try older version of MySQL JDBC driver (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43604963/phpstorm-mysql-connector-j-stopped-working-after-update-to-5-1-40). No other bright ideas (I do not have CloudPlatform account so cannot test/verify anything myself).